# Should I buy Ram memory DDR3 1066MHz for Mac mini (Mid 2011)?

Tags: memory, mac-mini

I got a Mac mini last year and now I want to update the ram memory. I was looking for it and I just found [this](http://articulo.mercadolibre.com.pe/MPE-19244084-ram-para-mac-8gb-_JM#!califications) (spanish). The guy is selling  what you see on the picture and I'm worried if I get those memories my Mac won't run ok. The guy says it works without problem on Mac Mini (Mid 2011) but I'm not sure because the image says "Laptop memory".

This info is about my mac:

- 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5
- 2 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
- And running OS X Lion.

Would you suggest to buy that memory? Or the should be X GB **1333** MHz DDR3?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why on earth would you put memory rated slower than the manufacturer specifies in your mac?

Comment: Because I was looking for ram memory on ebay but what I have found is from Hong Kong and I'm worried that I could would get some fake stuff (even if the seller has high rating). And the seller on the link says it works fine. Now I guess I will keep looking for the right one here in my country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This memory will work (Mac Minis use **SO-DIMMs**, also called laptop memory), but it will not use the full potential of your motherboard. This pair of Corsair is great for a 2010 MacBooks with 320m Nvidia.

If you are able, you should seek and buy **[DDR3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM)-1333Mhz SO-DIMM** (also called **PC3-10600**).

ps. I have checked the prices and 200PEN (google tells me that this is around 75USD) is way higher than the price you should pay (40-50 USD).

Comment: Slower rated memory _can_ work, but categorically saying all such memory will work seems unbelievably optimistic. Underclocking a chip can lead to lower [CAS latencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAS_latency), but over clocking them is usually a waste of your time and money.

Comment: Nobody is talking about overclocking here. Memory will not be overclocked and will work exactly the frequency and latency it's designed. I'm sure about Mac Mini i5 2.3gHz, because a friend of mine has it and he is using the "slower" (2x4GB 1066mHz DDR3 aka PC3-10600) from his older Mac Book Pro (mid 2010) and I did the swapping.

Comment: Cool - are you saying that all mac mini logic boards will slow down the memory access system to ensure slower RAM gets run at the slower rate? I've never seen any authoritative reference that shows that it happens - but I suppose anything is possible. In your case, how can you be sure your friend doesn't have chips that can run safely at 1333 MHz even though many parts labeled 1066 MHz cannot? Silicon chips get binned after manufacturing. They don't set out to make 1066 chips - those are just the ones that error at 1333, so they put them in a matching controller.

Comment: All boards will honour the DDR [SPD table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect) and that's the way all (non-buggy) hardware works. Those chips don't run at 1333, because this frequency is not described in the SPD table. Probably the chips could run it, but something should force the 1333mHz frequency, and this can be either flashing the SPD table, overriding SPD information from BIOS (which macs don't have) or EFI (never heard of someone doing it, but it's possible). ps. I did deep research and [this](http://tylermilner.com/?p=342) few months before this guy wrote this article.

Comment: Here is my [answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/11753/4474) covering RAM issues speed issues with the buggy mid 2010 MBP's NVidia 320M chipset and solution by flashing SPD chip.

Comment: Yeah, 200PEN is around 75 USD; but a long time ago I wanted to upgrade the ram and I can't find the right one (1333 MHz). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you think this article is right for me? http://www.ebay.com/itm/8gb-2x4gb-DDR3-1333mhz-SoDimm-Notebook-Memory-for-Apple-Mac-Mini-Mid-2011-High-/230771075895?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item35bb072b37#ht_2024wt_1262. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this will work, but the price is high for a unknown brand. I can recommend this [OWC item](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/1333DDR3S08S/) for it's price ($50) and guarantee to work, but every pair of **DDR3 PC3-10600 1333MHz SO-DIMM 204pin CL9 (9-9-9)** will work. Try a local dealer first, you should get even lower prices.

Answer (score 1):

To be sure you are getting something that will work I suggest shopping with a specialist Mac dealer like OWC, where you will be asked what machine you have and then you can choose from the memory they offer that fits it. They ship to Australia so Spain should be no trouble. Sure you can work it out and get something cheaper but I don't have time for that generally, don't mind supporting a dealer who supports my machine better and if it goes wrong I can say "but you said it would work!" (haven't needed to yet)

Besides I like having as much memory as possible and they offer a 16GB kit. With Xcode, Safari and Pixelmator open I often see more than 8GB in use.

I have only once kept the memory in a Mac when upgrading and in a mini with two memory slots you almost certainly won't. You will want to have two identical memory modules. The nice thing about the mini is that upgrading is so easy, you can get to the memory as soon as you take the bottom cover off.

For your Mac they offer 1333Mhz memory. Looks like it is what it came with also. I would personally not buy 1066MHz because even if it works perfectly it is possibly going to cause the memory bus to run a little slower than it could. RAM is so cheap right now and the wrong RAM can be a really big frustration, why take a chance?

Comment: Just to add: The retailer doesn't matter one bit so long as you know what you are buying. Any normal 1066Mhz DDR3 SO-DIMM RAM will work just fine and will (probably) be quite a bit cheaper at a local retailer or ordering it from a retailer from your own country.

Comment: Really, any will work fine? Apple says http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4805 - that's 1333MHz they specify and not 1066MHz. Any retailer yes, as I also said, IF you're prepared to do the research and be absolutely sure.

Comment: Yes, you are right, 1333Mhz is the correct one. 1066 *should* work as well, but getting the faster one is better. I just looked at the title of the question, not at the correct info.